# Google Classroom: How can I get the studentSubmissionId?

Tags: google-classroom

I have the courseWorkId, the courseId, and the student email. I have verified they're correct using the API explorer to get the data. I want to get the studentSubmissionId so I can patch the grade and assign a score. I am not swift with JSON and cannot seem to parse the value I get for the response below.

```
function getSubmissionId(stdEmail) {

    gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list({
          courseId: gCourseId,
          courseWorkId: gCourseWorkId,
          userId:'stdEmail'
        }).then(function(response) {

        // response.result...??
        // how to I parse this??

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check online on how to access [JSON Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp):

```
var myObj = { "name":"John",
              "age":30,
              "car":{
                      "brand": "Ferrari"
                    }
             };
x = myObj.age
y = myObj["car"]["brand"];

console.log(x); // returns 30
console.log(y); // returns Ferrari
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get the studentSubmissionId.

```
function getSubmissionId(stdEmail) {

var gStudentSubmissionID;

gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list({
      courseId: gCourseId,
      courseWorkId: gCourseWorkId,
      userId: stdEmail
    }).then(function(response) {

    gStudentSubmissionID = response.result.studentSubmissions[0].id;

    //console.log(response.result.studentSubmissions[0].id);
    console.log('associatedWithDeveloper: '+response.result.studentSubmissions[0].associatedWithDeveloper);  

    });

}
```